# Windows Phone 7 - Close or Do not initialize an application when internet connection is not available

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am developing an application which is fully depended on internet. So i can detect if the internet connection is available or not. But the problem is if the internet connection is not available i have to close the application or the application shouldn't be initialized.

What exactly i need is this. Two Scenarios one with internet connection available and other is not. When the application is opened with internet connection everything will be normal.

When internet connection is not available and the application is opened it should show a message box saying `"Sorry no internet connection is found. Application is now closing"` and go back to start screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this your App would not be certified to the marketplace. Even with that error, your app must be responsive.

I suggest you to create a placeholder in case there is no connection.

Answer (score 1):

Better is to introduce a option, like **shake to re-try connecting** (like the Facebook app). Just doing nothing, and enforcing a re-start of the application is a terrible user experience, and just poor craftsmanship.

And as mentioned by MSicc, any app closing down in any other way than via. the back-button, won't pass marketplace certification.

A mobile app needs to endure slow/no-connections in many situations, and it needs to be responsible even if you're doing a operation that requires internet access. If it's not, users will give you bad ratings, and nobody will use your app in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way that is supported with XNA.

```
new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game().Exit();
```

Comment: It does not matter.  You are allowed to have hybrid applications.  Think of an augmented reality application.  It might use XNA to place objects in the video stream but It is not a game.  XNA != game.  You are allowed to use it as a few applications already do.  The shortcut applications all used this when you hit the back button after clicking on a shortcut.